# IE6 Layout Issue - should be extremely simple

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-float

I'm building a simple HTML/CSS template for myself, which is [here](http://indoflips.com/2-col/), and it works great in everything but IE6. In IE6 the sidebar gets pushed down to the bottom which tells me that IE is getting the widths wrong.

The #wrapper div is 940px wide.
The #mainContent div is 730px wide
The #sidebar div is 209px wide.

730px + 209px = 939px

I am not using padding, margins, or borders on these divs... so I don't think it's the box model issue.

Anyone have any idea why IE6 breaks? I added the [IE7 Javascript Code](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) fix, but unfortunately I can't see if it works because Adobe Browser Lab and Netrenderer don't pick up the javascript.

If you could pop out Firebug and check out the [template](http://indoflips.com/2-col/) I'm sure some of you guys can spot what's wrong right away.

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See:** http://jsbin.com/itolaw/5

I added `float: left` to `#sidebar`, and `position: relative` to `#mainContent`. I also removed `IE7.js`.

I've tested it in IE6 by using [IE NetRenderer](http://netrenderer.com/), as you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest explicitly setting the widths of every object, that usually fixes the problem under IE6 (please remember that the outer width of the object is`width`+`margin`+`padding`, so when you calculate the desired width take that into consideration).

And it seems that you **are** using paddings.